# Git Commands to Server via SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I'm new to git and I tried to search on google first before i post my problem here but it seems I can't find the right answer in my situation or if its the correct one.

My question is how can I access remote server and issue git commands?

My superior gave me an ssh access (username,password,hostname). and he wants me to do the
following:

Create a /web folder.
Create a /dev respository inside /web folder 
Create and commit sample files within the /dev respository.

(That is in the server)

Now that the git is already set and folders created he told me to 
clone the respository in that server to my laptop and Push it backup.

I know the basic commands but I don't know what to start and how I can issue commands on that server.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you all the commands, but here's the outline.

1. SSH into the server: `ssh username@hostname`. This gets you into a terminal that you can use as you would locally.
2. Navigate to appropriate folder, create `web` and `dev` directories.
3. Inside `dev`, initialize the repository.
4. Create, commit your changes.
5. On the laptop, use the `clone` command to pull your new repo down. You'll have to do something along the lines of `git clone username@hostname:/path/to/web/dev.git`.

Comment: hi! Thanks for your help. But still have question, I already connected to server via ssh and already make web and dev directories. my problem is i can't issue git commands. it says git command not found. how can I initialize git commands while connected to that server? It seems it only accepts bash commands?

Comment: @Yassi Sorry for the late response. If any command starting with `git` is not found, then git is not installed on that machine. If it's a debian-based OS like Linux, then you need to issue the command `sudo apt-get install git` before you can use it. That'll download the git packages along with any dependencies.

Comment: Hi there. i tried sudo apt-get but still, command can't be found :(

Comment: Did the first set of commands successfully install git? Which OS are you on?